# How to print multiple text files within a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have reached a little bit of a brick wall. I understand how to print a single text file within a batch file via Notepad but I am stuck when it comes to multiple text files. Here is what I have so far that really is not working correctly at all:

```
set /P PrinterFile= "Enter File Name:" | set PrinterFile2= "" | set PrinterFile3= "" | set PrinterFile4= "" | set PrinterFile5= ""

if %PrinterFile%== ""(
    echo please enter valid file
    pause
) else (
    notepad.exe /P %PrinterFile%
)

pause
```

I did not finish the `if` statements to check for the others because I cannot get the first one to work. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thank you!

In the end it needs to be able to take from 0 to 5 text files. for example (name of batch file is `printer.bat`):

```
printer   file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: There is a syntax issue: `if "%PrinterFile%"=="" (` (note the additional quotes and the moved space)

Comment: for some reason it still just exits and never actually outputs the text file into notepad.

Comment: Yes, because of your first line; I just wanted to point out a syntax error, but I did not provide a solution; what you are looking for is called "command line arguments" -- see the [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command (type `call /?` into a command prompt window and read the help)...

Comment: ya thats what i thought. I'm trying to allow the user to enter multiple text files (up to 5) on a single line within the command prompt and then attempt to print those files within notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printfiles.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%f in (%*) do (
 if exist "%%~f" (notepad.exe /P "%%~f"
 ) else (
  if exist "%%~f.txt" (notepad.exe /P "%%~f.txt"
  ) else (
   echo "%%~f" not found
  )
 )
)
```

[untested]

This should work. It simply processes the namelist provided as a parameter so

```
printfiles abc,def,ghi,yellow.txt
```

would print the files (`abc` or `abc.txt`) and (`def` or `def.txt`) and (`ghi` or `ghi.txt`) and (`yellow.txt` or `yellow.txt.txt`) if the files exist.

Does that solve your problem?

---

Full-blown version

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Get file list from command line
SET "filelist=%*"
IF DEFINED filelist GOTO printthem
CLS
ECHO Press ENTER to START printing
:nextfile
SET "filename="
SET /p "filename=Print : "
IF DEFINED filename SET "filelist=%filelist%,"%filename%""&goto nextfile
IF NOT DEFINED filelist ECHO no files specified&GOTO :EOF

:printthem
for %%f in (%filelist%) do (
 if exist "%%~f" (notepad.exe /P "%%~f"
 ) else (
  if exist "%%~f.txt" (notepad.exe /P "%%~f.txt"
  ) else (
   echo "%%~f" not found
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

First thing : load `filelist` from command-line, so executing `printfiles abc,def,ghi,yellow.txt` would assign `abc,def,ghi,yellow.txt` to `filelist`. If there are no supplied parameters, assign *nothing* to `filelist`.

If `filelist` is defined (ie, contains a value which implies command-line parameters were supplied)  then go to the label `printthem`

Otherwise, clear the screen and how the message `Press ENTER to START printing`

Then set `filename` to *nothing* (because `set /p` with simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> will leave the value **unchanged**) and prompt for input with `Print :`. Keyboard input will be placed into `filename`.

if there was a (presumed, filename) entry made, then accumulate `"the filename"` to the end of `filelist` after a comma and repeat the request for a filename.

When simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> is used, `filename` will be empty, hence undefined so we proceed to `:printthem` provided `filelist` is not empty.

From there, we simply process `filelist` as a comma-separated series of 
filenames into `%%f`. If the filename as-entered exists, use notepad to print it, if it doesn't, try appending `.txt` to the name and if even that fails, show an error message.

The `%%~f` removes the quotes from the item in `%%f`. This is then re-quoted so that `filenames containing spaces` may be printed.

Comment: Is this supposed to work on its own or should i keep my first line?

Comment: All you need is what I've posted. If you really want to go through a prompt-and-accept cycle, then it's easy to arrange.

Comment: If you have time, could you explain each line?